# Find user using email + password in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, devise

My Rails app uses data from legacy database. Imported users from this DB contain duplicate emails. Authentication doing with email+password (and it's a unique combination in DB).
Devise uses method `find_for_database_authentication` to find user. However params don't contain password (just login name).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search this way

in the User model override the find method:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
   conditions = warden_conditions.dup

   email = conditions.delete(:email)
   pwd = conditions.delete(:password)
   encrypted_pwd = User.new(password: pwd).encrypted_password

   where(conditions).where(["lower(email) = :email AND encrypted_password = :pwd", { :email => email.strip.downcase, :pwd => encrypted_pwd }]).first
end
```

And probably config/initializers/devise.rb will require smth like:

```
 config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :password ]
```

Comment: Method self.find_for_database_authentication is in User model class and params is not accessible

Comment: I mean you can get the encrypted_password form devise using User.new with the credentials you have. Edited the answer to match your comment

Comment: This is in Devise controller (in gem), not in my controller

Comment: my warden_conditions don't contain password at all - only username

p warden_conditions
{:login=>"asdasdasd"}

Comment: Thanks! I missed config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :password ]

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
find_user = User.where("email = ?", params["user"]["email"]).first
find_user.valid_password?(params["user"]["password"])
```